# Bubble plot for three observation

Tags: r, ggplot2

This my data. I m trying to put three column in my bubbleplot.

They are Altered, Unaltered and the associated survial q value

My data frame

```
    dput(df)
    structure(list(Class = c("cell fate commitment", "chromatin remodeling", 
    "chromatin_covalent", "demethylation", "histone methylation", 
    "intracellular receptor signaling pathway", "negative regulation of cell differentiation", 
    "Nuclear Receptor transcription pathway", "PID HDAC CLASSI PATHWAY", 
    "PID SMAD2 3NUCLEAR PATHWAY", "regulation of chromatin organization", 
    "Transcriptional misregulation in cancer"), Altered = c(182, 
    312, 433, 117, 354, 294, 258, 268, 244, 185, 197, 282), Unaltered = c(489, 
    361, 235, 559, 315, 370, 411, 409, 426, 491, 483, 387), `q-Value` = c(0.0009732, 
    1.1e-07, 2.832e-05, 0.137, 0.003188, 0.971, 0.139, 0.0008647, 
    0.002938, 2.843e-06, 3.102e-06, 0.032)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
    "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), spec = structure(list(
        cols = list(Class = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
        "collector")), Altered = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
        "collector")), Unaltered = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
        "collector")), `q-Value` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
        "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
        "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

> ```
> Code for the plot
> ```

```
    xm <- reshape2::melt(df, id.vars = "Class", variable.name = "Samples", value.name = "Size")
    
    # Calculate bubble size
    bubble_size <- function(val){
      ifelse(val > 3, (1/15) * val + (1/3), val)
    }
    
    # Calculate bubble colour
    bubble_colour <- function(val){
      ifelse(val > 3, "A", "B")
    }
    
    # Calculate bubble size and colour
    xm %<>% 
      mutate(bub_size = bubble_size(Size),
             bub_col = bubble_colour(Size))

# Plot data


ggplot(xm, aes(x = Samples, y = fct_rev(Class))) +
  geom_point(aes(size = bub_size, fill = bub_col), shape = 21, colour = "black") +
#  geom_text()
  geom_label_repel(aes(label=Size), size=3)+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = alpha("gray", 0.5), linetype = "dashed"),
        text = element_text(family = "serif"),
        legend.position = "none") + 
  scale_size(range = c(1, 25)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue","red")) +
  ylab("Class")
```

I get something like this

[image: my figure]

How do I label the two patient group into different color as well as label the data point such as patient number for both group and the qualue in the plot

**Update**
I can put label into the plot. But not able to map two different colors for the patient group altered and unaltered group.

Updated fig

[image: updated figure with labels]

Comment: Can you review these sentences: "If I would go for the class and the last column this was one of the solution given to me which would work absolutely fine." and "My objective is to show the patient both altered and unaltered each class and the q-value which tells about the survival." ... possibly with a native speaker of English and rework so it can be parsed correctly? I am unable to make sense of what is desired.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're aiming at. You could map ```Samples``` to the color of the labels: ```...geom_label_repel(aes(label=Size, color = Samples), size=3)+...```